# Gatling active users drops to negative for a longer run after timeout exception

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm running a simulation using gatling.
5 users per second for 150 mins.

After a certain exception:

```
15:58:19.643 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.GatlingHttpListener - Request 'facebook_outbound_msg' failed for user 29989

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out

at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)

15:58:19.643 [ERROR] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - Request 'facebook_outbound_msg' failed for user 29989: j.n.s.SSLException: handshake timed out

15:58:19.643 [ERROR] i.g.h.c.i.DefaultHttpClient - Failed to install SslHandler

15:58:19.678 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.GatlingHttpListener - Request 'facebook_inbound_msg' failed for user 29984

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out

at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)

15:58:19.678 [ERROR] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - Request 'facebook_inbound_msg' failed for user 29984: j.n.s.SSLException: handshake timed out
```

the number of active users dropped to -1, then everytime this exception happens, the number of users keeps dropping.

Example:

```
---- FacebookOutboundSimulation ------------------------------------------------
[############################################                              ] 59%
          waiting: 18061  / active: -3     / done: 26942 
---- FacebookInboundMessageSimulation ------------------------------------------
[############################################                              ] 59%
          waiting: 18061  / active: -3     / done: 26942 
================================================================================
```

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.0.0-RC1 when I switched to gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.0.0-RC3 that was released on 2nd October 2018 it got resolved.

Sidenote: Use AsJson instead of AsJSON.